# Overlay, disappear on click, reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I got this dashboard where some components are zoomable by scroll.

I wish to activate this component by the first click on it. So it should be covered by a black overlay background with transparency. A text in the center "Click to activate". Click on it, the black background disappears.

Something like this.

```
export const OverlayClick: React.FC = (props) => {
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = React.useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="w-100 h-100" style={isClicked === false && { background: "#000000", opacity: 0.5, zIndex: 1000 }} onClick={() => setIsClicked(true)}>
      Click to activate
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Not working. Any ideas?

Comment: `isClicked === false` evil. Simply use `!isClicked`. In JS you can simply test if the value is `true`, not 0, not null, etc, by doing `if (variable)` or similar. Adding `!` will flip it form `true` to `false` check. ALSO instead of adding `style` and funky behavior, why not render a different component, that is the black screen, and after `OnClick` render your wanted component `isClicked ? <ComponentA /> : <ComponentB />`? This way you cna easily lazy load the content if there is a lot for the user behind the black box. If the user didint click it - dont waste resources rendering it.

Comment: Looks like it works to me: https://jsfiddle.net/dqzm05jf/1/ (I did switch it to class based, but the same principles apply. I just didn't use useState())

Answer (score 0):

```js
const OverlayClick = (props) => {
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = React.useState(true);
  const styles = isClicked ? {} : { background: "#000000", opacity: 0.5, zIndex: 1000 };
  return (
    <div className="w-100 h-100" style={styles} onClick={() => setIsClicked(!isClicked)}>
      Click to activate
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

const elem = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<OverlayClick><div>bla</div></OverlayClick>, elem);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```